# C# select in webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I need to get a table from the site. To do this, I load the webpage into webbrowser. But beyond that, I need to select from the drop down menu the desired option, then the page should be updated. Then I will work with the html code. It turns out that I need to update the data in webbrowser. How do I implement it?
That's how I tried to choose the desired option:

```
foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.All)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("name") == "Time")
    {
        element.Children[6].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Time").InvokeMember("onchange");
    }                                  
}
```

But it did not change the content of webbrowser.

Edit:I missed, that it is ajax table.

Comment: if you want jquery like css selectors, use html agility pack and fizzler https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/

Comment: If you are trying to scrape data, take a look at HTML Agility Kit, it makes working with the DOM much simpler and faster.

Comment: is this in the C# or the JS?

Comment: My code? It is in the C#.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following before to change drop down values. It seemed to work well.

```
HtmlElement reportDropDown = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("dropdown_control_id");
reportDropDown.Focus();
reportDropDown.SetAttribute("value", "Backup Status Report");  //The value of the desired selection
reportDropDown.InvokeMember("onchange");
reportDropDown.RemoveFocus();
```

I created a sort of state machine. This was just one step that had to be performed.